# Vega Lite - Animated bar charts without looping

Tags: powerbi, visualization, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I came across a fantastic article on animated visualizations using Vega-Lite, which you can find here: https://vis.csail.mit.edu/pubs/animated-vega-lite/

However, what I'm currently exploring is whether it's possible to create an animation in Vega-Lite that smoothly transitions from 0 to its respective value and stops there.

For instance, with bar charts, triggered by a filter change etc.

Does anyone happen to know if this is possible?

Attaching sample data:

```
{
  "width": 400,
  "height": 220,
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "ceiling_value",
      "value": 4000
    },
    {
      "name": "increment",
      "value": 1,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "timer{70}",
          "update": "increment + 500"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "dataset",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "day",
          "expr": "datum['day']"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "value",
          "expr": "clamp(datum['zero_measure'] + increment, 0, ceiling_value)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {
        "data": "dataset",
        "field": "day"
      },
      "range": "width"
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": [0, 6000],
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "left",
      "scale": "yscale"
    },
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "xscale"
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "dataset"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {
            "scale": "xscale",
            "field": "day"
          },
          "width": {
            "scale": "xscale",
            "band": 0.8,
            "offset": -1
          },
          "fill": {
            "value": "steelblue"
          },
          "cornerRadius": {"value": 4}
        },
        "update": {
          "y": {
            "scale": "yscale",
            "field": "value"
          },
          "y2": {
            "scale": "yscale",
            "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation is possible but it is manual and will require you to write the spec. You can see some examples of animation here on my GitHub and use the techniques yourself to build your viz.

https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

Take a look at Convex Hull, Covid Map, Deneb Bubble Text, Fireworks, Starfield

I can also recommend the smoothing functions from Madison Giammaria as well as a neat animation that demonstrates their use.

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/madison-giammaria-58463b33_powerbi-pbi-datavisualization-activity-7132225538361810944-45rE?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/madison-giammaria-58463b33_vega-deneb-powerbi-activity-7137122282727968769-Fh65?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop

[image]

Comment: wow, your visualizations look stunning..thanks...will try to experiment...but im not proficient in Vega so lets see :)

Comment: I'm almost there and have updated the code. But there's one thing I'd greatly appreciate help with—specifically, lines 5 to 8 in the code, concerning signal named 'ceiling_value.' How can I set it up to store the actual row value from a specified column? I want the bars to grow to their respective values and not to a hard coded one as in my example. This signal is passed to the clamp function on line 32. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a new question with the details and someone or myself will take a look

Comment: I just did. Thank you Davide!